# Did I tie it well? (Will it be used?)

Tags: word-usage

A little child ties a collar around his dog's neck and asks his mother:

> Did I **tie it well**?

Does it sound natural? Will it be ever used? I'm asking this because "well" sounds a bit formal. Or should it simply be : Is it okay? **But if "tying" has to be emphasized what will a natural word for that?**

So is "well" used in such sentences in daily life conversations natural?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds fine to me; I don’t think *well* is that formal. A small child might not know this word and use the (incorrect) adjective *good* instead of the (correct) adverb *well*, but a *well*-spoken child might very well be aware of the difference.

A more informal way a child might also ask this using the word *okay* is

> Did I tie this okay?

Or

> Did I tie it okay?

(*it* is acceptable in place of *this* if it is already clear what is being referred to)

I’m not sure it’s “standard” to use *okay* as an adverb (much like *good*) but a child could certainly form a question like that.